# Difference href and $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-site

I have a link on my webpage that goes to "/auth/facebook"

```
<a href='/auth/facebook'>Log In with Facebook</a>
```

This works fine.

I need to do the same thing in Js in a react component. This is the code

```
<a className='btn btn-primary btn-outline'
   role='button'
   onClick={() => $.get('/auth/facebook')}>

   Sign up/in to buy

</a>
```

When the Onclick is triggered the console outputs an error as if I was trying to execute a cross site request.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%…Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=public_profile&client_id=XXXX.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

My understanding is that both the link and the $.get call should go to my server "localhost" and trigger the same route. 
What is the difference between the two calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.GET` is just going to load data from the server (assuming it worked, and didn't throw a CORS error).  It doesn't handle redirection. If for some reason you can't use the `href` attribute, you can do something like:

`onClick={() => window.location.href = '/auth/facebook'}`

Since it looks like you're using react, you might also benefit from using a router module like react-router (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router), which exposes a `<Link>` component to keep your UI in sync with the URL.

Comment: This solved my problem. I am still a little confused on why it would fail though. Is the header sent from $.get different? why does it not handle redirection?

Comment: `$.get` corresponds with an HTTP GET request. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods